# Use replace() but keep the HTML in result

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Using jQuery how can I find and replace a word but keep the HTML? When I do `replace()` it returns a string with HTML stripped.

This is an example. I want to replace `Hello` with `Hi` but when I use this code the result is stripping away all the HTML. I know I can simply wrap the text with a unique selector, but it's not possible to edit the HTML.

```js
(function($) {
  var string = $('.banner-message');

  string.each(function() {
    var replaced = $(this).text().replace(/Hello /, 'Hi ');
    $(this).html(replaced);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

.banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner-message">
  Hello World
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
<div class="banner-message">
  Hello World
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n7L24ue5/

Thank you...

Comment: No, I can't. Just edited the question.

Comment: It's not stripping the HTML when you do `.replace` - `$(this).text()`returns you the *text* without the HTML. You then set the *text* as the *HTML*.

Comment: To add to the above, change `$(this).text().replace...` to `$(this).html().replace...`, just be careful not to replace any values which could be found *within* the HTML tags.

Comment: Use `html()` instead of `text()` thanks guys!

Comment: Also you can use [previousSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling) instead of using `replace()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do

```
var replaced = $(this).text().replace(/Hello /, 'Hi ');
-----------------------^^^^
```

The `.text()` function returns the *text* version of the content. You need the method to get the *html* version :)
*Hint: You already have the method you're looking for in that same snippet*

Comment: If you're going to hint at something just leave a comment. This isn't an answer.

Comment: Use `html()` instead of `text()` yes, I understand thank you : )

Comment: It was a bit big for a comment. And I can give the direct answer, but IMO a tiny bit of own thinking helps you remember it a lot better than just a given answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a span to your html, as so:

```
<div class="banner-message">
<span>Hello World</span>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>

<div class="banner-message">
<span>Hello World</span>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

And update the javascript:

```
(function($) {
  var string = $('.banner-message');

  string.each(function(){
    var replaced = $(this).find('span').text().replace( /Hello /, 'Hi ' );
    $(this).find('span').html(replaced)
  });      
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `I know I can simply wrap the text with a unique selector, but it's not possible to edit the HTML.`